# Зачем указывать запуск проекта 2 раза?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi

В процессе настройки проекта заметил одну особенность: проект запускается 2 раза (часть кода опущена)
ФАЙЛ **wsgi.py:**

```
from myproject import MyApp as app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

ФАЙЛ **myproject.py:**

```
MyApp = Flask(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

Теперь вопрос: зачем 2 раза его запускать? Это такая особенность или можно запуск убрать из **myproject.py**?

Comment: ну хз.. там два проекта запускается app и MyApp

Comment: Да нет. Запускается 1 и тот же проект. Просто под разными именами. Сначала в файле wsgi, а потом в myproject

Comment: судя по именам, запускаются разные проекты... есть ли где либо присвоение перменным app и MyApp членами какого либо класса?

Comment: А, я кажется понял)) Скорее всего запускается только 1 раз - просто в разных ситуациях запускается по разному. Т.е. если разработчик хочет запустить проект и проверить его работоспособность, то он запускает файл myproject. А На сервере Gunicorn запускает файл wsgi.

Comment: Он запускается только в том файле, который вы запускаете в консоли. Чтобы он не запускался дважды и написан `if __name__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно. Перепроверил. Внутри файла **myproject.py** можно убрать код:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp.run()
```

И запускать через **wsgi.py** проект